# Get original matrix value from image

Tags: image, matlab

I have the following little problem:
I display an RGB image (derived from a matrix -> grayscale -> RGB) in a GUI. The picture shows the elevation of a surface. I´m searching for a way to click on a certain pixel in my RGB image and get the real elevation value (contained in the *original* matrix).
I found `P = impixel(RGB,c,r)` which returns me the RGB value, but I have no clue how to trace or convert this back to the original value in `matrix`. Another idea could be to get the value directly from my original matrix using the x,y position in the grid, but this involves quite some code I guess...
Any clever ideas around?

Answer (score 2):

Use the other output arguments of [`impixel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impixel.html):

```
[C,R,P] = impixel(...)
```

From the docs:

> If you supply three output arguments, impixel returns the coordinates of the selected pixels

Then lookup the value in your *source matrix* with `R` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the marker-functionality in your Matlab-figure. It will tell you x, y, and the respective value at the selection location.